# google play service conflict error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

In one of my project getting google play service error.
Bellow is my gradle file and getting error -

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.2.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.zhy:flowlayout-lib:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2')
            {
                force = true;
            }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'android.lib.recaptcha:reCAPTCHA:+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.11.1'
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.14.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile project(':emojilike')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How can i resolve above problem. please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

try this update your **play-services-location**

> **make same version of Firebase or Google Play Service**

**use this**

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2')
```

**instead of this**

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2') {
   force = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2')` to version `11.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your always you should add same version of google play services.

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2')
{
.....
}
```

to

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2')
{
.......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same version of **Firebase/Google Play Service**. You're using the following:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2') {
   force = true;
}

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.0.2'
```

which is have a different version. Change it to the same version which is `11.0.2`. Then remove the `force = true` because you probably don't need it:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
```